# how to make a system curl call from terminal using python?

Tags: python

The call I want to make is this:

```
curl -i \
  -H 'Harvest-Account-ID: 3012210627'\
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 184740.pt.VgNF7lMe1YDTjTH4_nfhm8NiH(qMyRI9kFS4BBvztnLM9P0HNgQvAHnlglnTA9q0wlmtrpoEONHVaT7phZAaNw'\
  -H 'User-Agent: Harvest API Example' \
  "https://api.harvestapp.com/api/v2/time_entries.json"
```

but I am not quite sure of how to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `requests`: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Hi vineet. If you made an attempt at this in Python, [edit] your question, include your attempt, and describe the problem you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

It does not authenticate, because you did not send the JWT Token in HTTP headers:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Harvest-Account-ID": "380637",
    "Authorization": "Bearer 184740.pt.VgNF7mMe1YDTjTH4_nfhm8NiT5IMyRI9kFS4AAvztnLM9P0HNgQvAHnlglnTA9X0wlmtrpoEONHVaT7phZAaNw",
    "User-Agent": "Harvest API Example"
}
print (requests.get("https://api.harvestapp.com/api/v2/time_entries.json", headers=headers)
```

Returns:

```
<Response [200]>
```